# AutoResize property in treeview in window form

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I want to resize treeview based on treenodes. When it expand i want to show all item but when it collapse i want to show just root node and decrease height of treeview. I just tried is any property similar to auto resize but it was not found. If anybody help me on this problem it will be great.

Comment: `QTreeView` is different from `TreeView`. I noticed you have asked the question about `TreeView` but used `QTreeView` tag. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4):

You can send [`TVM_GETNEXTITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvm-getnextitem?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message to [`TreeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), passing `TVGN_LASTVISIBLE` as `wParam` to get the handle of last node of the treeview.

Then you can call the internal `NodeFromHandle` method to get the node from handle. Then you can use `Bound` property of the node to find its bound. `Top` + `Height` of the last item, determines required height of `TreeView`:

```
const int TVM_GETNEXTITEM = 0x1100 + 10;
const int TVGN_LASTVISIBLE = 0x000A;
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern static IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

void AdjustTreeViewHeight(TreeView treeView)
{
    treeView.Scrollable = false;
    var nodeHandle = SendMessage(treeView.Handle, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, 
        TVGN_LASTVISIBLE, IntPtr.Zero);
    var node = treeView.GetType().GetMethod("NodeFromHandle",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Invoke(treeView, new object[] { nodeHandle }) as TreeNode;
    var r = node.Bounds;
    treeView.Height = r.Top + r.Height + 4;
}
```

Cal above method after adding/removing nodes, also in `AfterCollapse` and `AfterExpand`:

[image]