# Scroll TreeView with MouseMove

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView and nodes on it. I want to scroll with the MouseMove Event. I did this for panel weeks ago but panel have the AutoScrollPosition property to do that so it's easier. How can I do with a TreeView that don't have the AutoscrollPosition property ?

I tried this :

```
        private void TreeViewFilters_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            return;
        }
        if ((startPoint.X == treeViewFilters.PointToClient(MousePosition).X) && (startPoint.Y == treeViewFilters.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y))
        {
            return;
        }

        Point currAutoS = treeViewFilters.AutoScrollPosition; //Problem here
        if (startPoint.Y > treeViewFilters.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y)
        {
            if (startPoint.Y != 0)
            {
                currAutoS.Y = (Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y) + 15);
            }
        }
        else if (startPoint.Y < treeViewFilters.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y)
        {
            currAutoS.Y = (Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y) - 15);
        }
        else
        {
            currAutoS.Y = Math.Abs(currAutoS.Y);
        }

        if (startPoint.X > treeViewFilters.PointToClient(MousePosition).X)
        {
            if (currAutoS.X != 0)
            {
                currAutoS.X = (Math.Abs(currAutoS.X) + 15);
            }
        }
        else if (startPoint.X < treeViewFilters.PointToClient(MousePosition).X)
        {
            currAutoS.X = (Math.Abs(currAutoS.X) - 15);
        }
        else
        {
            currAutoS.X = Math.Abs(currAutoS.X);
        }

        currAutoS = treeViewFilters.AutoScrollPosition; //and here
        startPoint = treeViewFilters.PointToClient(MousePosition);

    }
```

Please someone can help me ?

Comment: [`TreeView.TopNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.topnode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) 
and [`TreeViewGetNodeAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.getnodeat?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) should help.

Comment: You should also be able to send a `WM_VSCROLL` message.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57500577/3110834) shows how to auto-size treeview. You can host it in an auto-scroll panel, make the treeview auto-sized. Then use panel's auto scroll position.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I tried your third proposition because the first is not what I want but I don't know how to do that exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it works :

```
                treeViewFilters.Location = new Point(treeViewFilters.Location.X, -vScrollBarFilters.Value);
```